# MessageBox.Show background colors

Tags: vb.net, core

me gustaría saber cómo puedo cambiar el color de las ventanas de MessageBox ya que soy nuevo le pregunté a AI Chat pero no fué muy específico.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo más simple es que te crees tu una form a modo de ventana emergente